# Clover code coverage with multi module project

Tags: maven, code-coverage, clover

I'm trying to configure clover with maven.
In parent pom file the lover configuration is as fallowed:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <configuration> 
          <licenseLocation>c:\clover.license</licenseLocation>
          <reportDescriptor>C:\clover-report.xml</reportDescriptor>
          <includesTestSourceRoots>false</includesTestSourceRoots>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I have multi module project look like this:

```
 <modules>
      <module>module1</module>
      <module>module2</module>
      <module>module3</module>              
 </modules>
```

and running clover by:

```
mvn  clover2:setup test clover2:aggregate clover2:clover
```

The problem is clover is building clover.db only for the first module (module1) and not for the rest modules .
What should I do in order to make clover go over all modules?

I have also tried it without aggregate without success.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your last two other modules were compiled before and as a consequence javac did not recompile sources instrumented by Clover. Try to add the "clean" goal:

mvn clean clover2:setup test clover2:aggregate clover2:clover